# How do I check whether my job pays out unused PST?

Tags: quitting, relationships, sickness

I get paid by the hour. I leave in two weeks, and have around 3+ days of paid sick time accumulated. I want to use this, of course, but I also don't want to leave my employer hanging without someone to fill in, as my position is crucial every day.

I would like to ask my employer directly if PST is payed out when we leave, and if not, I would like to suggest that she schedules me and one other person to handle my position on days where I may just happen to fall sick. However, I can see this going over poorly, and I'd like to maintain good a relationship with management.

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: It's just a restaurant, Cafe Zupas to be precise. I don't even know if we *have* an HR Department.

Comment: You can ask if they will pay out PST when you leave. Apparently you have to find someone to take your shift to call in sick: https://www.glassdoor.ca/Benefits/Cafe-Zupas-Sick-Days-US-BNFT33_E390713_N1.htm - then there's the question of "happening to fall sick".

Comment: Ask whomever does payroll, they might have the answer if there isn't a dedicated HR dept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your quandary--this is a delicate situation but I think your best option is to be forthright about what you want.  Ask your manager or whoever is in charge of human resource matters if you will be paid for your unused sick leave and if not, if it will be possible to use it before your last day.  If the answer to both of these questions is "no," you will have to decide whether getting the sick time you've earned is worth the potential for putting strain on your future relationship with your employer.  When you put in two weeks notice, it's generally expected that you are planning to work the two weeks as scheduled.

The way you ask really depends a lot on the type of relationship you have with the people in charge. If they're somewhat easy going, you may be able to get away with, "so say I should happen to fall ill over the weekend *wink* *wink*, could you get someone to cover my shifts?"

Comment: Another way to frame it (without hinting at leaving) is to ask if your unused days 'expire' and if so, if it is possible to cash it out before it does.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ask your human resources department, saying that you have a general question about the what the policy is.  This way, you can potentially avoid ruffling feathers with management.